# Adobe Experience Manager AEM 6.2. Image cropping instead of Image Squeeze

Tags: image, workflow, aem

I am using "DAM Update Asset" workflow. I am able to resize the image to the height and width I want. however there is a problem, instead of cropping the image, it is squeezing the image into the required size. is there any way from which I can crop the image instead of squeezing it?

Comment: Not sure about the workflow but I've used a [servlet that comes with _ACS AEM Commons_](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/named-image-transform.html) to transform images on the fly. Note, however, that it doesn't save the output in the content repository. An image will be generated in response to an HTTP request and returned to a client. We ended up encrypting the crop parameters to prevent a DOS vulnerability and relied on dispatcher caching to avoid an unnecessary load on the publishers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you add the "Resize Image" workflow step to your workflow.
This does not support cropping, only resizing. I dont think there is a crop step Out of the box.

Fortunately, it is very simple to create a custom workflow process, you simply need to create an OSGi Service for the `com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec.WorkflowProcess` interface. There you could implement some logic to crop your file manually (you would need to use some API to manipulate the image, I can't help you with this). You can find an example on how to create a workflow process [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-custom-aem-workflow-steps.html)

To then add it to your workflow, you can use a "Process Step", while configuring it, your process should appear in the list.